# No configuration setting found for key 'conf' while trying to use ConfigFactory.parseString

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, typesafe-config, application.conf

I am trying to read my application.conf which is stored in in my s3 bucket.I used Bufferedsource to read from s3 but when I try to use `ConfigFactory.parseString(source.mkString).getConfig("conf")`  it did not find the 'conf' which is there.Below is my source code :

```
import com.amazonaws.auth.DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.S3Object
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.{AmazonS3Client, AmazonS3ClientBuilder, AmazonS3URI}
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._

import scala.io.{BufferedSource, Source}


object Test {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {


    import com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials
    val credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("key", "secertkey")
  //  val credentialsProvider = new DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain()
    val s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(credentials)
    val uri: AmazonS3URI = new AmazonS3URI("s3://test-buck/conf/application.conf")
    val s3Object: S3Object = s3Client.getObject(uri.getBucket, uri.getKey)

    val source: BufferedSource = Source.fromInputStream(s3Object.getObjectContent)
    try {
      println(source.mkString)
      import com.typesafe.config.{Config, ConfigFactory}
      val rawConfig: Config = ConfigFactory.parseString(source.mkString)
      val rootConfig = rawConfig.getConfig("conf")

      println(rootConfig)
//      println(rotConfig)
    } finally {
      source.close()
    }

  }
```

}

My application config looks like below

```
  conf {
    
       source_data_list = ["OL", "SB","1CP"]
//some other value
    
 OL {
    filename = "receipts_delta_GBR_14_10_2017.csv"
    sftp_conf {
      hostname = "endpoint"
      port = "22"
      username = "ubuntu"
      pem = "pemfile"
      filetype = "csv"
      delimiter = "|"
      directory = "/home/ubuntu/data"
    }

  }
    }
```

Not sure what i am doing wrong here .Same application config if i put on resource and try loading by `ConfigFactory.load("application.conf").getConfig("conf")` it works as expected .
Any clue on this would help .

Exception I got

Exception in thread "main" Exception in thread "main" com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$Missing: No configuration setting found for key 'conf'
at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.findKey(SimpleConfig.java:124)
at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.find(SimpleConfig.java:145)
at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.find(SimpleConfig.java:159)
at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.find(SimpleConfig.java:164)
at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.getObject(SimpleConfig.java:218)
at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.getConfig(SimpleConfig.java:224)
at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.getConfig(SimpleConfig.java:33)
at com.dsm.utils.Test$.main(Test.scala:26)
at com.dsm.utils.Test.main(Test.scala)

Comment: Could you also provide the error message? That would be helpful.

Comment: @Yann I updated the exception  got

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you succeeded to read the configuration.

The issue you're having is because of `BufferedSource`. The Buffered source can be read once. You read it, in order to debug, I guess, and then the source gets to the end. The second time you read it, in order to populate `rawConfig` you get an empty string. I solved it by extracting the configuration string into a variable, and then using it.

```
val config = source.mkString
println(s"config is: $config")
val rawConfig: Config = ConfigFactory.parseString(config)
val rootConfig = rawConfig.getConfig("conf")
println(s"rootConfig is: $rootConfig")
```

The output is:

```
rootConfig is: Config(SimpleConfigObject({"OL":{"filename":"receipts_delta_GBR_14_10_2017.csv","sftp_conf":{"delimiter":"|","directory":"/home/ubuntu/data","filetype":"csv","hostname":"endpoint","pem":"pemfile","port":"22","username":"ubuntu"}},"source_data_list":["OL","SB","1CP"]}))
```